# When do we need to set ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute to True?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets a value indicating whether to use the operating system shell
//     to start the process.
//
// Returns:
//     true to use the shell when starting the process; otherwise, the process is
//     created directly from the executable file. The default is true.
[DefaultValue(true)]
[MonitoringDescription("ProcessUseShellExecute")]
[NotifyParentProperty(true)]
public bool UseShellExecute { get; set; }
```

If we spawn a new process, when do we need to set UseShellExecute  to True?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

The `UseShellExecute` boolean property is related to the use of the windows [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) function vs the [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) function - the short answer is that if `UseShellExecute` is true then the `Process` class will use the `ShellExecute` function, otherwise it will use `CreateProcess`.

The longer answer is that the `ShellExecute` function is used to open a specified program or file - it is roughly equivalnt to typing the command to be executed into the run dialog and clicking OK, which means that it can be used to (for example):

- Open .html files or web using the default browser without needing to know what that browser is,
- Open a word document without needing to know what the installation path for Word is
- Run any command on the `PATH`

For example:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "www.google.co.uk";
p.Start();
```

It is very easy to use, versatile and powerful however comes with some drawbacks:

- It isn't possible to redirect the standard input / output / error handles
- It isn't possibly to specify security descriptors (or other cool things) for the child process
- There is a potential to introduce security vulnerabilities if you make assumptions about what will actually be run:

  ```
   // If there is an executable called "notepad.exe" somewhere on the path 
   // then this might not do what we expect
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
   p.Start();
  ```

`CreateProcess` is a far more precise way of starting a process - it doesn't search the path and allows you to redirect the standard input or output of the child process (among other things).  The disadvantage of `CreateProcess` however is that none of the 3 examples I gave above will work (try it and see).

In summary, you should set `UseShellExecute` to false if:

- You want to redirect the standard input / output / error (this is the most common reason)
- You don't want to search the path for the executable (e.g. for security reasons)

Conversely you should keep `UseShellExecute` true if you want to open documents, urls or batch files etc... rather than having to explicitly give the path to an executable.

Comment: Great Stuff, but you write that (with ShellExecute),  "It[you claim] isn't possible to redirect the standard input / output / error handles" <-- Surely that is incorrect or inaccurate. Even with useShellExecute set to true, while indeed you can't do  `processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput=true`,  it seems to me you can still redirect standard output by doing  `process.Arguments= "cmd /c dir >c:\\crp\\a.a"`. Likewise from a run dialog box you can do `cmd /c dir>c:\crp\a.a`

Comment: also,    you say that when `UseShellExecute=false` i.e. CreateProcess, won't check the path, but I see that even when I do  "UseShellExecute=false" i.e. supposedly not checking the path, then  process.FileName="cmd.exe"  works so it is checking c:\windows\system32. And if I copy cmd.exe to c:\windows and name it cmmmd.exe then I do process1.FileName="cmmmd.exe" that works too so it's checking c:\windows  so it seems like it's checking the path, or some bunch of directories.

Comment: MSDN docs agree with @barlop: "When UseShellExecute is false, the FileName property can be either a fully qualified path to the executable, or a simple executable name that the system will attempt to find within folders specified by the PATH environment variable."

Comment: By setting `UseShellExecute` to `true` I was able to share an environment variable (that was only created in the calling process). Very handy

Answer (score 20):

I think mostly for non-executables. For instance if are trying to open a `.html` file, if you'll have to set `UseShellExecute` to `true` and that will open the `.html` in a browser that's set as default by the user.

Answer (score 13):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx):

> Setting this property to false enables
>   you to redirect input, output, and
>   error streams.
>
> UseShellExecute must be false if
>   the UserName property is not null or
>   an empty string, or an
>   InvalidOperationException will be
>   thrown when the
>   Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo) method
>   is called.
>
> When you use the operating system
>   shell to start processes, you can
>   start any document (which is any
>   registered file type associated with
>   an executable that has a default open
>   action) and perform operations on the
>   file, such as printing, with the
>   Process component. When
>   UseShellExecute is false, you can
>   start only executables with the
>   Process component.
>
> UseShellExecute must be true if you
>   set the ErrorDialog property to true.

Answer (score 0):

When the path contains a space or some other special (i.e. accented) characters, CreateProcess (UseShellExecute=false) seems to be using short file names ("DOS" 8.3 notation), ShellExecute (UseShellExecute=true) uses long file names.
So when you use UseShellExecute=false, make sure to convert your directory and file names to 8.3 names (google ".net how to get 8.3 filename").
(Not exectly sure what Windows versions and/or file systems do it this way, tested on Windows 7, NTFS.)

Comment: Could it be that it is just cutting off the path at the space? Putting quotes around the "path/program name" solves this.

Answer (score -1):

If we want to hide the current Application executable window , Then UseShellExecute should be set to true