Windows form buttons fail to launch resources
I created a windows form using C#, the form contains buttons and labels and a tab control.
Every button and label has different functionality. For example, some buttons open different browsers, and some other buttons open windows applications and utilities such as “Regedit” and “Active Directory”.
This form is used by users who need to launch the form with “Elevated account”.
The users login to their computers with their regular ID account. Example GS22551. Their elevated account is GS22551.4
When the users launch the form under their regular account, every button and label functions perfectly! When they click on a button, the resource is called and it opens to them. But, when they launch the form with their elevated account, the one ends with .4 (shift + right click ‘run as different user’) the form buttons that should open “Regedit” and “Active Directory” fail and the user gets the following error message

Error “Unhandled exception has occurred in your application If you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue”

An error occurred trying to start process
‘C:\Windows\regedit.exe’ with working directory
‘C:\Form1’. The requested operation requires elevation
Users get this error only when they open Regedit” and “Active Directory”
For example, if they click on the button to that opens “Computer Management” they do not get that error.

Please share your actual code - not a vague description thereof.

Do you understand how Windows User Account Control (UAC) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/application-security/application-control/user-account-control/how-it-works) works? A normal user can only run an app in non-admin mode. A user with elevated privileges can run either in non-admin mode, or run in elevated mode. In order to do the latter, the laughing app must be running with an elevated token, or the user must choose to "run as admin". Why do you have two accounts per user? You seem to be (unsuccessfully) duplicating UAC capabilities

@Dai thanks for the quick response! Is there a specific object/block of code you need?
Regedit
private void regedit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Process.Start("C:\Windows\regedit.exe");
}
Active Directory
private void AD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Process.Start("mmc.exe", "dsa.msc");
}

@Sammie You have to provide a way for people to reproduce the problem you're facing.

@Sammie Process.Start(String) won't work with UAC elevation. You need to use ProcessStartInfo with Verb = "runas" and more besides. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872764/starting-another-process-with-elevation-using-different-user-credentials

@Flydog57 you're absolutely right, I just tried "Run as administrator" and it worked! But when I  Shift + Right click then choose "Run as a different user" that when I get the error message. In both occasions, whether I choose to "Run as a different user" or "Run as administrator" I get prompted to pick an elevated account and I choose to login with the .4 account

@Dai I tried your suggestion, and it worked like a charm :)
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
FileName = "mmc.exe",
Arguments = "dsa.msc",
UseShellExecute = true,
Verb = "runas"
Thank you all so very much! Specially you Dai!

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += ...
There are two types of enxceptions not caught by the usual trycatch on a stack. Those are ThreadExceptions and Unhandles Exceptions. You can still fetch them and get more information about what causes them:
Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(...);
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
