# BCDEDIT not recognized when running via C#

Tags: c#, windows

When i try to run BCDEDIT from my C# application i get the following error:

> 'bcdedit' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command,
>   operable program or batch file.

when i run it via elevated command line i get as expected.

i have used the following code:

```
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"CMD.EXE";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C bcdedit";
            p.Start();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            String error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            return output;
```

i have also tried using

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"BCDEDIT.EXE";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"";
```

i have tried the following:

1. Checking path variables - they are fine.
2. running visual studio from elevated command prompt.
3. placing full path.

i am running out of ideas, 
any idea as to why i am getting this error ?

all i need is the output of the command if there is another way that would work as well.
thanks

Comment: Try putting bcdedit in your debug/bin folder and see if that works. Also you're fine calling BCDEDIT directly, you don't have to run cmd.exe

Comment: @Mataniko , thanks - placing it in the debug directory seems to work, but why  doesn't it find the one in system32 path ?

Comment: It's the path settings, the answer by David Heffernan seems like the likely culprit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is one explanation that makes sense:

1. You are executing the program on a 64 bit machine.
2. Your C# program is built as x86.
3. The `bcdedit.exe` file exists in `C:\Windows\System32`.
4. Although `C:\Windows\System32` is on your system path, in an x86 process you are subject to the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx). Which means that `C:\Windows\System32` actually resolves to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.
5. There is no 32 bit version of `bcdedit.exe` in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

The solution is to change your C# program to target `AnyCPU` or `x64`.

Comment: Thank you !!! , you are correct.
Was going crazy trying to figure it out. thanks for the help !

Comment: Also worth noting, i saw in another SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255086/when-do-we-need-to-set-useshellexecute-to-true)  that when using **p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;** PATH does not get used as expected.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant. It's pure and simple that bcdedit.exe is not in the path, when redirected for wow64.

Answer (score 6):

If you are stuck with x86 application on both 32it/64bit Windows and You need to call bcdedit command, here is a way how to do that:

```
private static int ExecuteBcdEdit(string arguments, out IList<string> output)
{
    var cmdFullFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),
                                       Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess
                                           ? @"Sysnative\cmd.exe"
                                           : @"System32\cmd.exe");

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(cmdFullFileName, "/c bcdedit " + arguments) { UseShellExecute = false, RedirectStandardOutput = true };
    var process = new Process { StartInfo = psi };

    process.Start();
    StreamReader outputReader = process.StandardOutput;
    process.WaitForExit();
    output = outputReader.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
    return process.ExitCode;
}
```

usage:

```
var returnCode = ExecuteBcdEdit("/set IgnoreAllFailures", out outputForInvestigation);
```

Inspiration was from this thread and from [How to start a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003573/how-to-start-a-64-bit-process-from-a-32-bit-process) and from http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm