# Running Process on Server via ASP.NET/C# on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

What I am trying to do is run a batch file that is located on the webserver's desktop when a button is clicked.  This is what I have thus far.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("Notepad.exe");
   psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories";
   psi.UseShellExecute = false;
   psi.UserName = "administrator";  //username
   psi.Password = secure;  //secure string
var process = Process.Start(psi);
```

When I debug it, it does exactly what I want it to, but when I access the site on IIS (localhost:81) the batch file never runs.  I've tried many different variants of ProcessStartInfo and Process with no luck.  I've tested the username and password and they are both correct too.

I don't get any errors, the button just triggers a page post back.

I have given IUSR and IIS_IUSRS permissions to the file, and still nothing runs. I also removed the username and password and set the UseShellExecute to true, but that did nothing as well.

EDIT:

It looks like everyone thinks its some permissions.  Any idea on what I need to do to allow IIS to open the process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be running under the context of the user account that is running the website (AppPool)....

Comment: This really sounds like permissions on IIS. Try to impersionate a user instead, something similar. This is all kinda new to me aswell

Comment: try: psi.Verb = "runas" and also psi.ShellExecute=true

Comment: I agree with the others, it sounds very much like a permissions issue.

Comment: @Prokzy: In a comment below you said: "nothing pops up on the server".  What's in your batch file?  Because you shouldn't see a window open ..

Comment: @ChrisLively Now instead of testing on the batch file, I am trying to open notepad.  As soon as I get something to work I'll make it open the script it needs to.

Comment: That will never work.  IIS can't interact with the desktop.

Comment: Is there no workaround to this?

Comment: See this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1757464.aspx?how+to+give+permission+for+iis+user+for+execute+cmd  However, IIS wasn't built to support this type of thing and they even went out of their way to make it really really hard.  I'd suggest you go some other route.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll probably look into doing this project another way.  I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the third line to this:

```
  psi.UseShellExecute = true;
```

or read this article which really gets the work done:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;889251

Comment: Are you sure? Using the Shell on a web server sounds like a veeeeeeeeeeeeery strange idea.

Comment: @UweKeim but so does running a batch file on the desktop of the administrator user account, so... ;-)

Comment: UweKeim this risk exists from the start as @slippyr4 says! Just read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255086/when-do-we-need-to-set-useshellexecute-to-true

Comment: IMHO, a desktop vs publicly(?) accessible, though OP didn't really say, web server...Big difference in strange factor :)

Comment: When I try and run with the suggested answer, it still does the same thing. Nothing pops up on the server.  I'm guessing its some permissions, but I'm not sure exactly what it is.