# How to give permission to a C# Console application from Asp.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application, web-hosting

When I try to launch my console application from my web application on my local machine it works perfect, but when I try to do it on hosting server after publish I get `"Access is denied"` error.

This is the code where I call the console application, in case of that if you want.

```
      try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startinfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/ConsoleApplications/WebConsol.exe");
                startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startinfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                Process myProcess = Process.Start(startinfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.InnerException);
                }
            }
```

How can I give permission to the console application in order to avoid `"Access is denied"` error? Do I need to to it in my project or is it about web hosting server?

Note: I want to launch the console application to use as TCP server to implement a tcp listener.

Edit: My hosting provider is Arvixe.

Comment: Why do you need to launch a console window from your web application? What are you trying to do by doing that? It could be a trust issue; who's your provider?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I will add them in my question as details.

Comment: ask the provider if it is allowed to do that. should you succeed you may discover that the server is accessible only on port 80/443 (not unusual) so your listener cannot be reached. also your account may be terminated if this behaviour is not supported and/or explicitly forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention in another answer, you should add these lines of code:

```
startinfo.UserName = username;
startinfo.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
```

plus:

```
startinfo.UserShellExecute = false;
```

You can get more information here:

1. [Link1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ef205eca-ff5d-4cfc-922f-95650734aef6/processstart-with-useshellexecute-false)
2. [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805751/running-process-on-server-via-asp-net-c-on-iis)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough privilege in the hosting environment to run such application?

If you do, try setting the username and password of account who has privilege to execute it:

```
startinfo.UserName = username;
startinfo.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
```