# Process.Start(path) is not opening the file in Default Desktop Application

Tags: c#, process.start

I am trying open a downloaded file in it's default desktop application e.g. if that's a '.txt' file this should open in notepad and if it's a ('.docx') file, this should be opened using 'wordpad.exe' (if MS Word is not installed). I am trying to open the file using very common 'Process.Start()' method:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

where 'path' is the complete path to the file i.e. c:\somefolder\file.extension

Code is working in the sense that it's being executed without any errors (debugged this as well), and when I check the task manager, relevant process (notpad.exe, wordpad.exe, based on file being opened) is there in the process list. **BUT**, The desktop application is never launched to show the file.
Please guide what am i missing.

Comment: It is a little bit unclear, what is the "Desktop Application" ? Where the "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);" runs ? is it a service app ?

Comment: sorry, i meant native desktop app i.e. notepad for a txt file, wordpad for a docx file

Comment: Looks like you want to use shell execute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255086/when-do-we-need-to-set-useshellexecute-to-true

Comment: try System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd /c start \""+path+"\"");

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided there isn't much information to go on. A simple step would be to check what the value of the variable is and paste it in run to see if it actually executes. It might be a tiny issue.