# Java command through CMD not working in C#.NET

Tags: java, c#, cmd, path, command

I'm trying to run a java command in `cmd` using C# to get some inputs for my program, the path for Java is set correctly, and I am able to run Java commands in the `cmd` without any trouble but when I tried it in C#, it's showing " 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. " as if the path is not set.

But I am able to run the same command outside, don't know what seems to be the issue, kindly help, thanks in advance!

```
string cmd = @"/c java -jar """ + $"{treeEditDistanceDataFolder}libs" + $@"\RTED_v1.1.jar"" -f ""{f1}"" ""{f2}"" -c 1 1 1 -s heavy --switch -m";
Console.WriteLine(cmd);
var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Process started");
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine("Output was read");
string error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is your problem:

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

When `UseShellExecute` is `true`, the system and user `PATH` variables will be used if the application to launch is just the executable name. Because you're setting it to `false`, and `java` doesn't exist in your application's folder, it isn't possible for .NET to find it.

You have two options:

1. Set `UseShellExecute` to `true` so that it can use the `PATH` variable to find java.
2. Use a fully qualified path, e.g. `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java"`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255335/3181933) for more info.