# Start File with C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\TextFile.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR GIVEN: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a `ProcessStartInfo` object that specifies that you want to use the _Shell_ to start things up. The shell understands file associations (like "use Notepad to start `.txt` files). Otherwise it will try to start your file as an `EXE`, which it is not

Comment: Text files (`TextFile.txt` or any other `txt` file) are not executable. You have to use the shell's file associations to tell it to use the default application to *open* the text file.

Comment: In other words, try this string instead `@"notepad.exe C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\TextFile.txt"`

Comment: @h0r53: That's incorrect. You should do as Flydog57 suggested and use `ProcessStartInfo`, and let the user's default text editor (which may not be Notepad) open the file.

Comment: That would work in .Net Framework, where `UseShellExecute = true` by default, the opposite in .Net Core / .Net 5+, so you need to set it explicitly to `true` (in any case, more *migration friendly*).

Answer (score 1):

To launch a file with the default application, use `ProcessStartInfo` and set `UseShellExecute` to `true`.  For example:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("file.txt") { UseShellExecute = true });
```

For further reading, see [When do we need to set ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255335/138200).

`UseShellExecute` is defaulted to `true` for the full .Net Framework, so the above is equivalent to:

```
// NOTE: Only for .Net Framework - will not work on .Net Core / .Net 5+
Process.Start("file.txt");
```